# Pass constant through scripts

Tags: php, routes, constants

All pages are redirect to `index.php` where I read the URI and redirect to the pages.
Once I defined a constant on `index.php`:

```
define('ROOT_DIR', __DIR__);
```

How can I pass this constant to the other pages?

If I use

```
header('location:www.mysite.com/page_requested.php')
```

the constant is not defined and I cannot use it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Include the file what contains the constant wherever you want it. You can use a file named config.php that contains all your constants and include it wherever you need them.

Comment: If you dont want to include any file, you just have cookies or sessions to pass the constant to other pages. You can also pass the constant on the URL this way:
location:www.mysite.com/page_requested.php?constant=value,
but i don't think you want to

Comment: Yes, but of course there is a way to use on the whole site constant automatically!